# In Cordova app - iOS 15 shows white blank screen when the app is relaunched

Tags: cordova-plugins

Cordova app - iOS 15 shows white blank screen when the app is relaunched.

I tried removing and adding the cordova-plugin-splashscreen but could not get the result.

Comment: Does this happen in the emulator? Logs show anything?